# Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug' while generating debug apk. Correct apk file path

Tags: android, build, apk

I just upgraded my Android Studio to 3.0 and upgraded gradle version to 4.1,since then I am having issues generating apk files(debug and release both). It says:

> Execution failed for  task ':app:packageDebug'.
>
> > Cannot create directory:E:\StudioWorkspace\projectLocation\app\build\outputs\debug\E:\StudioWo‌​rkspace\projectLocat‌​ion\app\build\apk.

It's taking wrong file path and I am not able to correct it. 
I cleaned and rebuild the project ,also tried invalidate cache and restart, but hey don't seem to solve it.

How can I correct the apk generation path?

Comment: Did you get solution? Im facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had just commented the code

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFileName = file("$project.buildDir/apk/Name.apk")
        }
    }
```

in **Project->app->build.gradle** file. After that rebuild and launched in the emulator. It worked successfully.

Correct me if i am wrong..:)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, Sorry , I posted a wrong error log . What's actually happening is  my android studio is trying to create file on a directory that doesn't exist. It says :
Cannot create directory:E:\StudioWorkspace\projectLocation\app\build\outputs\debug\E:\StudioWorkspace\projectLocation\app\build\apk